# How can I make NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrentLocale() return just the date?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nslocale

`NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrentLocale()` makes formatting i18n dates really easy.

For example:

```
NSDate().descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrentLocale()
```

Returns:

```
Monday, February 1, 2016 at 12:00:00 PM Pacific Standard Time
```

Is there a way I can modify this simple function to return just the date? If not, how would I build out an equivalent NSLocale object that behaves the same way, deriving the an appropriate international date string?

I would expect, for `en_US`, it could return simply:

```
Monday, February 1, 2016
```

Comment: just use NSDateFormatter  `.dateStyle = .FullStyle`. The locale it is the current locale by default. If you would like a specific locale just set your dateFormatter.locale to whatever you need

Comment: `let df = NSDateFormatter()
df.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "pt_BR")
df.dateStyle = .FullStyle
df.stringFromDate(NSDate())
`

Comment: Ah, thanks Leo. Toss this in as an answer and I'll accept.  `extension NSDate() { func asFullStyle() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .FullStyle
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
    } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use NSDateFormatter .dateStyle = .FullStyle. The locale it is the current locale by default. If you would like a specific locale just set your formatter.locale to whatever you need

```
extension NSDate {
    struct Date {
        static let localizedFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
           let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateStyle = .FullStyle
            return formatter
        }()
    }
    var localizedDecription: String {
        return Date.localizedFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}

NSDate().localizedDecription   // Friday, January 29, 2016"
```